# Unity Drag and Drop x and z position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try to make a Drag and Drop function in Unity3D.
How it should work:
I have an Object on a ground and i want to be able to just drag it around the ground.
I only want to change the x and the z position.

Sadly no Tutorial could help me out with this problem.
I tried raycasting and it worked to 'select' the Object but i could not change the position.
I managed to write a script to show me the mouse position in world Space but it isnt working really.
Can someone help me out with this and explain me how the code works?

What steps do i need to do so it works?

Comment: You need to share the code snippets you tried very specific to the flow specified your question. It would improve the readers to understand the problem and able to give you the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use raycast here and use the hit point as you position when dragging.

```
void MoveObject()
        {
                RaycastHit hit;
                float movetarget;
                //startPoint = hit.point;
                ray = GetComponent<Camera> ().ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
                Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 100, Color.yellow);
                if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
                {
                    movetarget = hit.distance;
                    if (activated == false)
                    {
                        wall = Instantiate(prefab, hit.point, prefab.transform.rotation);
                        activated = true;
                    }
                    startPoint = hit.point;
                }
                wall.transform.position = hit.point;    
        }
```